# send data to create incident to Dynamics 365 with Python Requests post() Method

Tags: python-3.x, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I try to writing code to send data to create incident to Dynamics 365 with Python Requests post() Method but I have issue.
I use python 3.6,
I use this code but it give me this error

```
{'error': {'code': '', 'message': "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}}
```

the code:

```
import requests  
import json

#set these values to retrieve the oauth token
crmorg = 'https://xxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/' #base url for crm org  
clientid = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' #application client id  
tokenendpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token' #oauth token endpoint
secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#set these values to query your crm data
crmwebapi = 'https://xxxxxx.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/Incident' #full path to web api endpoint  
#crmwebapiquery = 'contacts?$select=fullname,contactid' #web api query (include leading /)

#build the authorization token request
tokenpost = {  
    'client_id':clientid,
    'resource':crmorg,
    'client_secret' : secret,
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    
}

#make the token request
tokenres = requests.post(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)

#set accesstoken variable to empty string
accesstoken = ''

#extract the access token
try:  
    accesstoken = tokenres.json()['access_token']
except(KeyError):  
    #handle any missing key errors
    print('Could not get access token')

#if we have an accesstoken
if(accesstoken!=''):  
    #prepare the crm request headers
    crmrequestheaders = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
        'OData-Version': '4.0',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=500',
        'Prefer': 'odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue'
    }
    incidentdata={
    "title": "test",
    "customerid_account": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "forte_casetypeid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "forte_casecategoryid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "primarycontactid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "entitlementid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    }

  
    #make the crm request
    crmres = requests.post(crmwebapi, headers=crmrequestheaders, data=json.dumps(incidentdata))
    try:
        #get the response json
        crmresults = crmres.json()
        print(crmresults)


    except KeyError:
        #handle any missing key errors
        print('Could not parse CRM results')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest few things to fix and test the code.

1. Entity name should be corrected

Both of the below endpoints should work, but `incidents` is the right entity name.

```
crmwebapi = 'https://xxxxxx.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/incidents'
crmwebapi = 'https://xxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/incidents'
```

2. Remove `Prefer` headers, as they are only needed for `GET` requests

Try the below headers.

```
crmrequestheaders = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
        'OData-Version': '4.0',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }
```

3. While assigning lookup/navigation properties - use `@odata.bind`

Check below and adjust accordingly.

```
incidentdata={
"title": "test",
"customerid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)",
"forte_casetypeid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"forte_casecategoryid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"primarycontactid@odata.bind": "/contacts(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)",
"entitlementid@odata.bind": "/entitlements(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)",
}
```

Comment: while I'm trying to connect to dynamics through code i got this error

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectionError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /8d804f4c-1c56-4b6c-82c1-5b6ba09e01b3/oauth2/v2.0/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A37223A220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))   File "C:\Users\Forte Cloud\Downloads\CRM.py", line 23, in <module>     tokenres = requests.post(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)

```